# How to create a dictionary having string and function as key value pair in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am looking to create a dictionary that will have

```
let urlDict:[String:Func] = ["LOGIN":getLoginURL(), "RESET":getResetPasswordURL()]

func getLoginURL() -> String{
        if (sandbox == true){
            return sb_login_url
        }else{
            return live_login_url
        }
    }


    func getResetPasswordURL() -> String{
        if (sandbox == true){
            return sb_reset_url
        }else{
            return live_reset_url
        }

    }
```

The purpose of this dict is to get/map functions based on the `KEY` and as per `KEY` corresponding function must be called which in turn will return return urls.

I have tried naming the dictionary but I am unable to do it

```
let urlDict:[String:Func] = ["LOGIN":getLoginURL(), "RESET":getResetPasswordURL()]
let urlDict:[String:Function] = ["LOGIN":getLoginURL(), "RESET":getResetPasswordURL()]
let urlDict:[String:Functions] = ["LOGIN":getLoginURL(), "RESET":getResetPasswordURL()]
```

**EDIT 1**

```
 class Constants{
       private let sb_login_url = "http://IP_ADDRESS_COM/login_with_credentials"
        private let live_login_url = "http://google.com"


        private let sb_reset_url = "http://IP_ADDRESS_COM/forgot_password"
        private let live_reset_url = "http://google.com"


        func getLoginURL() -> String{
            if (sandbox == true){
                return sb_login_url
            }else{
                return live_login_url
            }
        }


        func getResetPasswordURL() -> String{
            if (sandbox == true){
                return sb_reset_url
            }else{
                return live_reset_url
            }

        }
  `    let urlDict: [String: () -> String] = ["LOGIN": Constants.getLog‌​inURL(), "RESET":Constants.getResetPasswordURL()]

    if let getFunc = urlDict[url_key] {
                let url = (getFunc()) // foo}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the type of the functions (which are common for both `getLoginURL` and `getResetPasswordURL`) for the `value` slot in the dictionary, namely `() -> String`, a zero-arguments function returning a `String` instance.

```
func getLoginURL() -> String {
    return "foo"
}

func getResetPasswordURL() -> String {
    return "bar"
}

let urlDict: [String: () -> String] = 
    ["LOGIN": getLoginURL, "RESET":getResetPasswordURL]
/*            ^^^^^^^^^^^- note that you do not _call_ the functions,
                           as this would result in a String instance */ 

// get a function reference from the dictionary and invoke it
if let getFunc = urlDict["LOGIN"] {
    print(getFunc()) // foo
}
```

---

After your comments below, as well as your edit, it seems you want the `get...` functions to be class members if your class `Constants` (i.e., marked `static`).

```
class Constants {
    static var sandbox = true
    // I've just added this to test your example

    private static let sb_login_url = "http://IP_ADDRESS_COM/login_with_credentials"
    private static let live_login_url = "http://google.com"

    private static let sb_reset_url = "http://IP_ADDRESS_COM/forgot_password"
    private static let live_reset_url = "http://google.com"

    static func getLoginURL() -> String {
        if (Constants.sandbox == true){
            return Constants.sb_login_url
        } 
        else {
            return Constants.live_login_url
        } 
    }

    static func getResetPasswordURL() -> String{
        if (Constants.sandbox == true){
            return Constants.sb_reset_url
        } 
        else {
            return Constants.live_reset_url
        }
    }
}

let urlDict: [String: () -> String] = 
    ["LOGIN": Constants.getLoginURL, "RESET": Constants.getResetPasswordURL]

// get a function reference from the dictionary and invoke it
if let getFunc = urlDict["LOGIN"] {
    print(getFunc()) // http://IP_ADDRESS_COM/forgot_password
    Constants.sandbox = false
    print(getFunc()) // http://google.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a global `typealias` to Function prototype and can use it anywhere in your project and you don't need to use `() -> String` everytime when you create Dictionary.

```
public typealias VoidToStringFunctio‌n = () -> String

func getLoginURL() -> String {
return "url"
```

}

```
func getResetPasswordURL() -> String {
return "password"
```

}

and use it like this

```
let urlDict : [String: VoidToStringFunctio‌n] = ["LOGIN": getLoginURL, "Password": getResetPasswordURL]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution, particularly as the typealias `Function` is _very_ broad (and says nothing of the actual type it associates to), while it in fact (in the example above) is associated only with a single specific (function/closure) type. Possibly applicable by using more descriptive typealias names (e.g. `VoidToStringFunction`) but this just seems as unnecessary verboseness, as the type signature `() -> String` clearly says this on its own.

Comment: i agree @dfri Function is not good verboseness but i don't agree on this we should use () -> String everywhere.
what if he has more than 100 functions? using typealias is more readable.

Comment: Even if _"he has 100 functions"_, references to these would just be _instances_ in the `urlDict` above, whereas the _type_ of these functions (which we shall assume to be a single unique type, as we discuss using a `typealias` as an alternative) still only needs to be supplied in the type annotation of `urlDict`. Whether a `typealias` or an explicit type annotation is more readable is debatable.